# jqPlot BarRenderer bar width

Tags: jqplot

I have a dynamically generated jqPlot bar chart.  The number of categories along the bottom of the chart can vary quite considerably and some of them can have long labels.  For space reasons I don't wish to have angled labels.  What I was wondering was if there was any way that I could access the width of the individual bar elements and alter the width of the label css and set overflow to hidden based on this.  I understand that the BarRenderer component has a barWidth but I can't find out how to access that after the graph has finished rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hacky answer.  I figured that I could derive the bar width by subtracting the left positions of two adjacent x axis labels.

```
var firstXAxisLabel = $('#chart-id .jqplot-xaxis-tick:eq(0)');
var secondXAxisLabel = $('#chart-id .jqplot-xaxis-tick:eq(1)');
if (firstXAxisLabel.length === 1 && secondXAxisLabel.length === 1) {
  var barWidth = secondXAxisLabel.offset().left - firstXAxisLabel.offset().left;
  $('#chart-id .jqplot-xaxis-tick').width(barWidth);
}
```

Then in the css set the overflow to hidden:

```
.jqplot-xaxis-tick
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```